# Re-referencing objects

Tags: java, android, pointers, object, reference

I have a few objects I am modifying.
For instance (psuedocode)

```
Picture1.MoveToTheRight(50);
Picture2.MoveToTheLeft(50);
```

after I complete the operations I would like to re-reference these pointers.

So I would like `Picture1` to point to the Object of `Picture2`, and I would like `Picture2` to point to the Object of `Picture1`.

Later when I reference these objects, they will be in the proper order.

How can I manage this?

Essentially taking a few objects and swapping around their references.

Comment: You have googled for "java swap variables", right?

Comment: Just use a temporary variable already and be done with it.

Comment: Quite alot of aggression. My goodness. I wanted to know the most effective, best style way of doing it. I knew I could do it of course, but like most things in language there are better and worse ways of doing things. I did use google, but I did not come up with an elegant solution.

Comment: Not an *entirely* stupid question - some languages (eg Python) let you do things like `Picture1, Picture2 = Picture2, Picture1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious way:

```
Picture temp;
temp = Picture1;
Picture1 = Picture2;
Picture2 = temp;
```